# Python Subprocess Error

Tags: python

Попытался использовать стороннюю библиотеку с [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/junian/b41dd8e544bf0e3980c971b0d015f5f6), но в процессе использования кидает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/stream/twitch-recorder.py", line 147, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:/stream/twitch-recorder.py", line 144, in main
    twitch_recorder.run()
  File "C:/stream/twitch-recorder.py", line 64, in run
    self.loopcheck()
  File "C:/stream/twitch-recorder.py", line 111, in loopcheck
    subprocess.call(["streamlink", "--twitch-oauth-token", self.oauth_token, "twitch.tv/" + self.username, self.quality, "-o", recorded_filename])
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Danilshik\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Запуск с командной строки: `python twitch-recorder.py --user=zizaran`
В коде только заменил `"/Users/junian/Documents/twitch"` на `"/Users/Danilshik/Documents/twitch/"`

Перед записью `subprocess.call(["streamlink", "--twitch-oauth-token", self.oauth_token, "twitch.tv/" + self.username, self.quality, "-o", recorded_filename])` изменил переменную `recorded_filename` на `123.mp4`

Но ошибка все равно возникает. Есть идеи в чем может быть проблема?

Ошибка в Subprocess в этой строке `subprocess.call(["streamlink", "--twitch-oauth-token", self.oauth_token, "twitch.tv/" + self.username, self.quality, "-o", recorded_filename])`

Comment: Что дает запуск "stramlink" в cmd ?

Comment: Использование библиотеки streamlink https://streamlink.github.io/